# How do I convert the 'string' output to a number output in JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing this code where I need a number as a result. Check out the code below:

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
        with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
                read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
                return random.choice(list(read_hosts))[0]
```

the hostnumbers.txt file is like this:

```
1212
323
1314
45245
24
325
```

The output random output I need should be an integer. 
The current result I get is this: `"1212"`
Can you please help me with this? I need the result like this `1212`.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type-cast to integer:

```
read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)]
```

```
>>> with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
...     read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
...     read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)]
...     print(read_hosts)
...     print(random.choice(read_hosts))
... 
[1212, 323, 1314, 45245, 24, 325]
1314
```

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
I get this error when i try to run this

Comment: @bitch_ctrl seems like csv reader returns every line as a list, so updated the answer with change and an example run.

Answer (score 0):

To stay close to your approach:

```
with open('host.txt') as hosts:
    read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    print(int(random.choice(list(read_hosts))[0]))
```

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
I get this error when I try your approach